# How to connect On prem SQL Server (VM installed with SQL) from Azure Devops Release pipeline

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-devops

How to connect On prem SQL Server (VM installed with SQL) from Azure Devops Release pipeline. I have tried using SQL authentication but the connection is not enabling with SQL server. Any one tried / worked on this type of requirement before ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Azure devops is still blocked by your SQL Server. Did you just add the IP address of azure devops to the whitelist, but did not add the IP address of the machine where the hosted agent is located to the whitelist?

Refer:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#to-identify-the-possible-ip-ranges-for-microsoft-hosted-agents
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/allow-list-ip-url?view=azure-devops&tabs=IP-V4#ip-addresses-and-range-restrictions